# Using JasperViewer: export to pdf and Excel not working

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new to *DynamicReports*. I am currently working on one report using this framework and I am able to display the report data properly in JasperViewer. But when I try to save the data from JasperViewer in pdf or xls format I am facing some issues:

- Adobe is complaining that file it is not a supported file or file name is damaged.
- Excel is saying that extension does not match, I understand that this could be because I have xlsx in my machine and trying to open a file with xls extension.

1 - How to fix the pdf issue?
2 - How to save file in xlsx format ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is my code :

```
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
report.columns(Columns.column("Column 1", "column", DataTypes.stringType()))
.title(Components.text("Title")
.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
.pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
.setDataSource(dataSource)
.show(false);
```

Comment: `Adobe is complaining that file it is not a supported file or file name is damaged.` - What is the name and size of file? `Excel is saying that extension does not match, I understand that this could be because I have xlsx in my machine and trying to open a file with xls extension` - Did you try to change extension?

Comment: I was testing and gave a file name as test report and size of file is very small since there is only one record in the report. I think changing the file extension is not a solution for me as users will not prefer to do that

Comment: There is no code in how you save the pdf and the xlsx. How should we give hints if there is no code showing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was missing iText-2.1.7.jar file for pdf format and I was using an old version of poi.jar for excel format. 
The strange thing is jdeveloper didn't give me any error regarding these missing jars while I was saving the report in pdf or xls format from jasper viewer. 
Then I tried to open the report directly in browser in pdf format, then jdeveloper was complaining about missing iText-2.1.7.jar. Same thing happened with excel also.

Comment: `Then I tried to open the report directly in browser in pdf format, then jdeveloper was complaining about missing iText-2.1.7.jar.` - What do you mean? You got a message when you had opened a generated pdf file?